# php remove everything in the string, keep the last digits

Tags: php, regex

I have values like below:

```
$var1 = car-123-244343
$var2 = boat-2-1
$var3 = plane-311-23
```

I need to remove everything and keep the last digit/ditgits after the second hyphen

Expecting values:

```
244343
1
23
```

This is what I've got

```
$stripped = preg_replace('^[a-z]+[-]$', '', 'car-123-244343');
```

I got a big red error No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: A regex for this is overkill (see the answer from @Murilo)... unless this is just a learning exercise ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without regex:

```
$var1 = substr($var1, strrpos($var1, '-') + 1);
```

What this does is the same as:

1. `$pos = strrpos($var1, '-') + 1` takes the last postion of `'-'` and adds `1` for starting at the next character
2. `substr($var, $pos)` takes the `$var` and returns the substring starting in `$pos`.

I think is less expensive than using regex.

**Edit:**

As pointed below by konforce, if you are not sure which all the strings have that format, you have to verify it.

Comment: If you need to do validation, just break this up into two steps. If `strrpos` === `false`, then no dash was found.

Answer (score 2):

First, that error means your regex needs to be enclosed in [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (below I use the classic `/`).

Second, I would rewrite your regex to this:

```
$stripped = preg_replace('/.+?(\d+)$/', '$1', 'car-123-244343');
```

If you can operate on the *assumption* that what comes after the last `-` is always a number, the other solutions also work.

Answer (score 2):

this function will work:

```
function foo($value)
{
    $split = explode('-', $value);
    return $split[count($split)-1];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fun version with explode:

```
list($vehicle, $no1, $no2) = explode('-', $data);
```

Comment: **this** is a pretty smart one. Simple and easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

With regex:

```
$endnumber = preg_replace('/.*[^0-9]/', '', $input);
```

Remove everything up till, and including, the last non-digit.